# Move SQL Server database from one server to another

Tags: sql-server

We are using several servers with SQL Server 2008. We want to move a database from one server to another server. We did the following process

```
//   #1
detach database on first server

//   #2
physically copy database and log file to new server

//   #3
attach database on new server
```

our method did not work, the last step failed on the new server

Error msg like below

> BB error occurred while processing the log for database 'DBTEST'
>   If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
>   Could not open new database 'DBTEST'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted

Any change to recover with the current files, because I can now get these files again / get a backup version of the database files ? I do not know how to rebuild log files? I even can not attach them :-(

Comment: MSSQL can do that by itself, dont let delphi coders to break the process

Comment: @user539484: Language bashing is not allowed here. Please don't do it.

Comment: Writing code is not the way to fix this problem, regardless of what language you do it in. This is strictly a SQL Server issue, and should be asked as just that; it really has nothing to do with Delphi (and if it did, your question would be too vague to be answered).

Comment: @Ken White, no idea what you complaining about again. Yet, i second your motion to untag [delphi] for this Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are experiencing this error, I would recommend trying to attach the files back to the original server and see if you get any errors.  If the copied versions won't attach, then they may have been corrupted in some way.  If you still have the original version of the files on your source server, then try attaching them again to see if you get this error.  If you don't get an error, then you can recopy the files and try again.  If you get an error, then your only option is to restore from a backup.

Moving databases between servers through the detach and attach method should work so long as the version of target SQL Server is greater than or equal to the source SQL Server.  Although the error does not indicate this is the case, you may want to validate you have the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow the advice of your error message:

```
If possible, restore from backup.
```

Instead of detaching, copying, re-attaching, why not just run a backup and restore it to the new machine?

Never has failed me and I have moved 100's of databases around using this method.